# Dutch POS tags in R with openNLP

Tags: r

I downloaded the Dutch openNLPmodels.nl package for openNLP in R, with:

```
install.packages("openNLP")
install.packages("openNLPmodels.nl", repos = "http://datacube.wu.ac.at/", type="source")
```

I managed to get a list with words and their tags, from a sentence.
But I want to know what the POS tags mean.
I found a list of the CGN tagset, but it's not the same?

```
"De/Art"              "acrobaat/N"          "werkt/V"             "doorgaans/Adv"       "met/Prep"            "meerdere/Num"       
 [7] "acrobaten/N"         "samen/Adv"           "in/Prep"             "een/Art"             "circus/N"            "of/Conj"            
[13] "dansgroep/N"         "en/Conj"             "volgt/V"             "over/Prep"           "het/Art"             "algemeen/N"         
[19] "een/Art"             "strakke/Adj"         "choreografische/Adj" "show/N"              "die/Pron"            "het/Art"            
[25] "hele/Adj"            "jaar/N"              ",/Punc"              "en/Conj"             "soms/Adv"            "ook/Adv"            
[31] "langer/Adj"          ",/Punc"              "wordt/V"             "opgevoerd/V"         "./Punc"
```

Where can I find a POS tag list that matches the Dutch labels?

Comment: Hey @JeroenSteen have you found out in the meantime? I have the same problem.

Comment: I think the tagset is called WOTAN.